# Is there a JQuery plugin for the iPhone that will notify the user to "Bookmark" their app?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iphone, html, templates

Because it is not possible to force the iPhone to bookmark a webpage, I want a little arrow/bow to drop down to notify people to bookmark my mobile web page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think your question is limited to the iPhone. There are several implementations of "sliding" panels/boxes implemented in jQuery.

Check out [this one](http://web-kreation.com/demos/Sliding_login_panel_jquery/#). It's a login panel that slides when you click it, but I'm sure you could adapt it to be a ribbon that slides down after the page is rendered.

Answer (score 1):

For any future viewers I would like to add http://cubiq.org/add-to-home-screen

Comment: I use to this target iPhone and it is a great plugin, good looks.